# how to combine if else statements with javascript or linq.js

Tags: javascript, linq.js

what is the best way to combine this using javascript or linq.js? I am trying to shorten what I have done, it works correctly but I am trying to be more efficient with less code.

```
if (e.values.sqft == null) {
    updatedSqft = e.model.sqft
}
else {
    updatedSqft = e.values.sqft
}

if (e.values.price == null) {
    updatedPrice = e.model.price
}
else {
    updatedPrice = e.values.price
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updatedSqft = e.model.sqft == null ? e.values.sqft : e.model.sqft;
updatedPrice = e.values.price == null ? e.values.price : e.model.price;
```

Its called a *Conditional* or *Ternary* operator, see the [link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).  It's not specific to Javascript, you can also do this in other languages, such as `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try short hand code

format

```
variable = condition ? option 1 : option 2;
```

If condition is satified then option1 will be set else option2 will be set.

`null,undefined,""` will always return false.

Try like this

```
updatedSqft = e.values.sqft ? e.values.sqft : e.model.sqft;
updatedPrice = e.values.price ? e.values.price : e.model.price'
```

Answer (score 1):

For most programmers, what you did is the best way because of readability...
But, if you want a more compact code you can use something like the following:

```
// Ternary operator
updatedSqft = e.values.sqft ? e.values.sqft : e.model.sqft;
updatedPrice = e.values.price ? e.values.price : e.values.price;

// Logical OR
updatedSqft = e.values.sqft || e.model.sqft;
updatedPrice = e.values.price || e.model.price;
```

[Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) at MDN
[Logical OR Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) at MDN